# How to rerender search results with React

Tags: reactjs, react-router

So, I have a web application with a Search bar embedded into the global navbar. I want to be able to update the input fields in the search bar after the initial search and rerender the search results.

I've tried multiple things including a react-router redirect and a componentWillReceiveProps(), listening to browser changes, etc.

Below is my code. Any ideas on how to fix?

```
class SearchBox extends ComponentBase {

  constructor(props) {
  super(props);

 this.state = {
  dropdownOpen: false,
  location: '',
  term: '',
  distance: '50 mi',
  submitted: false,
  results: {}
 };

this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
this.select = this.select.bind(this);
this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
}

componentDidMount() {
 this.setState({
  location: this.props.city
 });  
}

toggle(e) {
  this.setState({
      dropdownOpen: !this.state.dropdownOpen
  });
}

select(event) {
  //let d = event.target.innerText.replace(" mi", "");
  this.setState({
      dropdownOpen: !this.state.dropdownOpen,
      distance: d
  });
}

handleChange(e) {
  const {
      name, value
  } = e.target;
  this.setState({
      [name]: value
  });
}

handleSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  this.setState({
      submitted: true
  });
  const {
      location, term, distance
  } = this.state;
  const {
      dispatch
  } = this.props;

  if (term && location) {
    let q = "?term=" + term + "&location=" + location + "&distance=" + distance;
    history.push("/results" + q);
   }
}

render() {
   const {
      location, term, distance
  } = this.state;

  return ( < form className = "form-inline" >
      < Input 
      type = "text"
      name = "term"
      id = "query"
      onChange = {
          this.handleChange
      }
      placeholder = "e.g., stationary" / > {
      } < Input 
      type = "text"
      name = "location"
      id = "loc"
      onChange = {
          this.handleChange
      }
      placeholder = "Location"
      value={this.state.location}
    />
   < Dropdown 
      id = 'distance'
      name = 'distance'
      size = "lg"
      isOpen = {
          this.state.dropdownOpen
      }
      toggle = {
          this.toggle
      } >
      < DropdownToggle caret > {
          this.state.distance
      } < /DropdownToggle> < DropdownMenu >
      < DropdownItem onClick = {
          this.select
      } > 5 mi < /DropdownItem> < DropdownItem onClick = {
          this.select
      } > 10 mi < /DropdownItem> < DropdownItem onClick = {
          this.select
      } > 25 mi < /DropdownItem> < DropdownItem onClick = {
          this.select
      } > 50 mi < /DropdownItem> < DropdownItem onClick = {
          this.select
      } > 100 mi < /DropdownItem> < /DropdownMenu> < /Dropdown>


      < Button 
      onClick = {
          this.handleSubmit
      } > < i className = "icon-magnifier" > < /i>&nbsp;Search</Button>
      < /form>
   );
  }
 }
```

This is how my routes are set up:

```js
class Full extends ComponentBase {

  constructor(props) {
    if (!props) props = {};
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      'city': '',
      'location': {},
      'contract_count': ''
    };

    const { dispatch } = this.props;
      history.listen((location, action) => {
      // clear alert on location change
      dispatch(alertActions.clear());
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.state.contract_count == '') {
      infoService.info()
        .then(
          results => {
            this.setState({
              city: results.data.city,
              location: results.data.location,
              contract_count: results.data.contract_count
            });
          }
        )
    }
  }

  //wait to render until we have state...
  preRender() {
    if (this.state.contract_count == '') {
      //wait
      return (<div></div>);
    } else {
      return (
        <ConnectedRouter history={history} data={this.state}>
          <div
               className="app setFont">
          <Header city={this.state.city}/>
          <div className="app-body">

            <main className="main">
            <Breadcrumb />

              <Container fluid>
                <div>
                  <PropsRoute exact path="/" name="Home" component={Home} data={this.state}/>
                  <Route exact path="/dashboard" name="Dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
                  <Route exact path="/cart" name="Cart" component={Cart} />
                  <Route exact path="/invoice" name="Payment/Invoice" component={Invoice} />
                  <Route exact path="/login" name="Login" component={Login}/>
                  <Route exact path="/register" name="Register" component={InitialRegister}/>
                  <Route exact path="/add-company" name="Add Company" component={AddCompany}/>
                  <Route exact path="/add-credit-card" name="Add Credit Card" component={AddCreditCard}/>
                  <Route exact path='/results' name='Search Results' component={SearchResults} />
                </div>
              </Container>
            </main>
          </div>
          <Footer />
        </div>
        </ConnectedRouter>
      );
    }
  }


  render() {
    return(
      <div>
      {this.preRender.call(this)}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
const renderMergedProps = (component, ...rest) => {
  const finalProps = Object.assign({}, ...rest);
  return (
    React.createElement(component, finalProps)
  );
}

const PropsRoute = ({ component, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route {...rest} render={routeProps => {
        return renderMergedProps(component, routeProps, rest);
    }}/>
  );
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const { alert } = state;
    return {
        alert
    };
}
const connectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps)(Full, store);
export { connectedApp as Full };
```

Comment: What does "update the input fields in the search bar after the initial search" mean exactly? And what *specific* issue(s) do you get? Also try to post only relevant parts of code, not just entire components.

Comment: there's two input fields (name, location) and a dropdown field (distance) and then when you press the search button it should take you to a results page...and then you should be able to change the fields and hit the button and have it rerender the results...currently it does nothing when you hit the search button

Comment: So in `handleSubmit()`, is it entering the `if (term && location){...}` block? And if so, is it pushing the value into history, but nothing happens? Also, any console errors?

Comment: right it's being pushed into the history the url changes in the browser address  bar but nothing happens and no console errors

Comment: Can you show the way you've set up your provider, router and route components in your root app component

Comment: So we can see how you're feeding in the redux store and react router history, and the way your routes are set up

Comment: just edited my question with that info

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't modify the history yourself. Instead you should store the path to redirect to in the state and then render a `<Redirect>` component [as described in the react-router docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow):

```js
class SearchBox extends Component {
    // ...

    handleSubmit = event => {

        // ...

        if (term && location) {
            this.setState({referrer: `/results?term=${term}&location=${location}`});
        }
    }

    render() {
        const {referrer} = this.state;
        if (referrer) return <Redirect to={referrer} />;

        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I feel like this answer is almost right on the money but it doesn't work, I get this error: warning.js?6327:33 Warning: Received `true` for a non-boolean attribute `block`.

Comment: i'm so close but i get an error message because it's not changing after I update the fields...I got an error message: You tried to redirect to the same route you're currently on: "/results?term=concrete&location=Palo Alto&distance=50 mi"